# CentOS search specific text in all files

Tags: centos

I need to find the files (and path to the files) on my CentOS 7 DirectAdmin server, that contains the string "qunar". So it needs to search all files inside the server.

How can I achieve that?

I tried this, but then the server does not respond, is that because of the heaviness of the search?

```
grep -i -R "qunar" /
```

Comment: Check below mentioned post you will find answer. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux)

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Magento?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Linux/Unix and not related to Magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

`-r` or `-R` is recursive

`-n` is line number, and

`-w` stands match the whole word.

`-l` (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.

In your case `grep -rnw '/' -e "qunar"`

Comment: So in my case it will be (grep -rnw '/' -e "qunar")?

Comment: yes in your case `grep -rnw '/' -e "qunar"`